# How do I update Rails from 3.2.7 to 4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, upgrade, activesupport

I tried to update Rails using:

```
sudo gem install rails --version 4.0
sudo gem install rails --version 4.0.0
sudo gem install rails -v 4.0
sudo gem install activesupport -v '4.0.0'
```

But, I always get the same error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing activesupport:
        activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

System Info:

```
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
Rails 3.2.7
```

What could be the problem?

## Update:

I found differences in terminals:

**in aptana studio:**

```
> gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/kai/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/

> gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
actionmailer (3.2.7, 3.2.6)
actionpack (3.2.7, 3.2.6)
activemodel (3.2.7, 3.2.6)
activerecord (3.2.7, 3.2.6)
activeresource (3.2.7, 3.2.6)
activesupport (3.2.7, 3.2.6)
arel (3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.12)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
builder (3.0.4, 3.0.0)
bundler (1.3.5, 1.0.0)
capistrano (2.13.5)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0, 1.3.3)
curb (0.7.12)
daemons (1.1.0)
devise (2.1.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
execjs (1.4.0)
flickraw (0.9.6)
highline (1.6.16)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1, 0.6.0)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.3, 2.1.1, 2.0.2)
json (1.7.5, 1.7.4, 1.5.1)
kgio (2.7.4)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
minitest (4.7.5)
msgpack (0.3.9apple)
multi_json (1.7.9, 1.3.7, 1.3.6)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.6.2)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
patron (0.4.11)
pg (0.10.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1, 1.2.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.6.1)
rails (3.2.7, 3.2.6)
railties (3.2.7, 3.2.6)
raindrops (0.10.0)
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
ref (1.0.2)
ruby_protobuf (0.4.11)
rubygems-update (2.0.6)
sass (3.2.3, 3.2.1, 3.1.20)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
sinatra (1.2.0)
sprockets (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
sqlite3-ruby (1.2.4)
thin (1.2.8)
thor (0.16.0, 0.15.4)
thread_safe (0.1.2)
tilt (1.3.3, 1.2.2)
treetop (1.4.12, 1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.37, 0.3.35, 0.3.33)
uglifier (1.2.7)
warden (1.2.1)
```

and so the ruby app with `require 'activesupport'` returns when start it:

```
/Users/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require': cannot load such file -- activesupport (LoadError)
    from /Users/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/kai/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/flickr_empty_project/app/app.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

**in bash:**

```
> gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/kai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/kai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/kai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
     - /Users/kai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/


> gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.0)
actionpack (4.0.0)
activemodel (4.0.0)
activerecord (4.0.0)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activesupport (4.0.0)
arel (4.0.0)
atomic (1.1.12)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.1.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
flickraw (0.9.6)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.23)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.7.9)
polyglot (0.3.3)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.0)
railties (4.0.0)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sprockets (2.10.0)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.2)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.14)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
```

Comment: Add the output of `which ruby; gem env` to your question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this documentation will help you. Please see the [link](http://programminginrubyonrails.blogspot.in/2013/08/upgrade-to-rails-4-and-ruby-2.html)

```
Step 1:
 rvm get head (to get the latest version of rvm)

Step 2:
 rvm install 2.0.0 (to install ruby)

Step 3:
 rvm use 2.0.0

Step 4:
 rvm gemset create rails4

Step 5:
 gem install rails
```

Comment: it helped to install the rails 4, but then problems in Update part raised

Comment: Please summarize the linked content. Link-only answers are frowned-upon because they break and are then worthless.

Answer (score 1):

Gem doesn't always seem to use the same path your shell uses. Try running `gem env` to see the RUBY VERSION and RUBY EXECUTABLE gem is using.

If as I suspect gem is using the Mac OS X system default (1.8.x) you can try forcing the path for the gem command:

```
PATH=<path-to-correct-ruby>:$PATH gem env
```

where `path-to-correct-ruby` might be something like ~/.rmv/rubies/default.

Comment: Gem doesn't use the PATH, it's bound to the Ruby that installed it. You can have multiple Rubies installed and each has its own gem set.

Answer (score 1):

Installing any gem using `sudo` will try to install or overwrite the gems for the built-in Ruby. Don't try to install Rails into the Mac's system version of Ruby; Leave Apple's Ruby alone, and install a copy of Ruby into a sandbox using RVM or rbenv instead.

Apple installed Ruby for their own use, not for yours. You can use it of course, but if you want to have something more modern than the default, install something more recent.

If you installed a Ruby for your own use using RVM or rbenv into your home directory into a sandbox, you do *not* need to use `sudo` ever when adding gems because you should have ownership and full privileges to administer those files.